# Azure Service Bus - No Subscription Error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I was trying to create a service bus messaging for my application to dump some information that I will process on a separate job. 
However, it say's that I have no subcription when I was trying to create a service bus. I'm not an admin and I was given a 'contributor' rights to it. Would that be the issue?

Comment: Please share some snippet.

Comment: What is the version of Azure SDK & Visual Studio your using?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Service Bus account on Azure Portal and that's when you're getting the error?